# C#: import "local" reference to library?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

This should be a pretty simple question, but it's quite hard to search for an answer.

In Python, you can import a library in two (primary) ways:

```
import myLibrary
thisObject = myLibrary.myObject()
```

Or:

```
from myLibrary import myObject
thisObject = myObject
```

Now, in C#, you normally use `using` to accomplish more or less the same thing:

```
using System;
```

However, notice in Python that the second option lets us write code that doesn't include a full namespace path reference to the object in question.

Once you start digging into .NET, there's some classes that are buried quite deeply. This can make for some "messy" code.

```
using System;
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey k1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey(...);
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey k2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey(...);
```

What I wish I could do is something (pseudo-code) like this:

```
using PublicKey from System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
PublicKey k1 = new PublicKey(...);
...
```

Now, I understand that it might not be feasible to import individual specific objects. But at the very least, could we import whole libraries locally? For example, System.Security.Cryptography is a collection. So:

```
using Cryptography from System.Security;
Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey k1 = new Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey(...);
...
```

Finally, this is probably not possible, but can we do anything similar to Python, where we can assign a more localized name to an import?

```
using Cryptography from System.Security as crypt;
crypt.AESCryptoServiceProvider acsp = new crypt.AESCryptoServiceProvider();
```

The real goal is just to have at least minimally more readable (and less repetitive) code.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It's important to note that namespaces aren't the same as libraries. But why aren't you just importing the whole namespace?

Comment: What you are looking for is an alias name for the long name spaces. This is possible in c#. Please have a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx) link.

Comment: I don't care about having to importing the whole namespace. The real point of the question was shortening the actual names of the classes within such namespaces. The answer below is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in C# for single classes or whole namespaces. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

```
 using PublicKey = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
 PublicKey k1 = new PublicKey(...);

 using crypt = System.Security.Cryptography;
 crypt.AESCryptoServiceProvider acsp = new crypt.AESCryptoServiceProvider();
```